# ServiceStack.Redis unable to connect sPort

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, nosql

I've been trying figure out for a few days now why I am getting exceptions such as https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiHzy.png

```
public virtual bool CreateOrUpdateValueById<T>(TQuery query, TResult value)
{
    using (var redisClient = Connection.RedisManager.GetClient())
    {
        var redis = redisClient.As<TResult>();

        var key = query.GetKeyWithId();
        redis.SetEntry(key, value);

        return true;
    }
}
```

which runs in loop of several hundred of items.

```
foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItems)
{
   var query = new PlaylistItemsQuery(playlistItem.Id, playlistItem.PlaylistId);
   _playlistItemsQueryHandler.CreateOrUpdateValueById<PlaylistItemDto>(query, playlistItem);
}
```

also happens for any get query

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TResult> GetAllValues(TQuery query)
{
    using (var redisClient = Connection.RedisManager.GetReadOnlyClient()
    {
        var keys = redisClient.ScanAllKeys(query.GetKeyWithAllIds()).ToList();
            return redisClient.GetValues<TResult>(keys);
    }
 }
```

i use singleton class for redispool

```
public static IRedisClientsManager RedisManager { get; } = new PooledRedisClientManager
{
    ConnectTimeout = 60000
};
```

I am hosting redis on localhost windows which is not officially supported, can this really be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests the Redis Client is unable to make a TCP Connection with the Remote Redis Server. If you're not using a licensed version of ServiceStack.Redis v4 then it could mean you've exceeded the ServiceStack.Redis [Free Quota Limits](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas).

Otherwise confirm that you can connect to it from `redis-cli.exe`, if you can't you can try restarting the redis-server.

Comment: I did not mention that first few thousands queries pass just fine. Restarting redit service did not help.

Comment: I could connect from redis-cli.exe and even run redis-benchmark.exe afterwards.

Comment: @ArturKokinArturK The error says client can't make a TCP connection to the server, this could be due by the load generated by `ScanAllKeys` see the v4.0.46 Release Notes which [explains how SCAN works](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md#improved-lua-support) and the LUA alternative. You can try [increasing the default Auto Retry limit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/Automatic-Retries) also printing the [Dump of RedisStats](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/Redis-Stats) which can provide health stats

Comment: I gave up and started using StackExange.Redis library instead :)

Comment: @aMerkuri no worries, I've had a closer look at this and it's likely you've exceeded the free quota limits due to the unbounded API calls the streaming ScanAllKeys generates under the hood to traverse the entire keyset. v4.0.47+ (on [MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) now) will have a clearer exception on the cause.